# InvalidOperationException when checking CaptureSource.State

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've created a class, which derives from `System.Windows.Media.AudioSink` to provide recording capabilities. To check the state of my concrete sink I do the following:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly MyAudioSink _myAudioSink; // this field is ensured in the ctor
    public bool IsRecording
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._myAudioSink == null)
            {
                return false; // I know that `false` is wrong ...
            }
            return this._myAudioSink.CaptureSource.State == CaptureState.Started;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I query against the proprety `IsRecording`, I get the following exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Capture source is not stopped
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource..ctor()
   at MS.Internal.CoreTypes.GetCoreWrapper(UInt32 typeId)
   at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.EnsureManagedPeer(IntPtr unmanagedPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Type type, Boolean preserveManagedObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertDO(IntPtr doPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertType(CValue outVal, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference, Boolean deleteBuffer, IManagedPeerBase fromObject)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.AudioSink_GetSource(AudioSink Sink)
   at System.Windows.Media.AudioSink.get_CaptureSource()
   at MyViewModel.get_IsRecording()
```

Sometimes when I do `this._myAudioSink.Stop()`, I get the following (similar) exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Capture source is not stopped
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at System.Windows.Media.CaptureSource..ctor()
   at MS.Internal.CoreTypes.GetCoreWrapper(UInt32 typeId)
   at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.EnsureManagedPeer(IntPtr unmanagedPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Type type, Boolean preserveManagedObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertDO(IntPtr doPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertType(CValue outVal, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference, Boolean deleteBuffer, IManagedPeerBase fromObject)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.AudioSink_GetSource(AudioSink Sink)
   at System.Windows.Media.AudioSink.get_CaptureSource()
```

So ... what's the reason for that? How can I prevent this exception (except introducing my own field and set it in the overrides of `OnCaptureStarted` and `OnCaptureStopped`)?

The only topic on this problem I've found on the net is [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-camera-and-microphone-support.aspx) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with overriding the specific commands (`OnCaptureStopped`, `OnCaptureStarted`, ..) to encapsulate the state in my model *AND* encapsulated the captureSource inside my concrete audio-sink in a separate field.

Obviously this does the trick, and I never had any problems again.

PS: I somewhere read that the encapsulation of the captureSource should be sufficient - atm I cannot provide the link ... it's somewhere out there, sry!